# saving figure in a loop matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on using a for loop to produce graphs for each set of data I have. Each plot prints correctly however the savefig() portion of my code only saves the last plot under each file name.

Here is a section of my code

```
total = 3
idx_list = []
dct = {}

for i, df in enumerate(graph_list):
    data = pd.DataFrame(df)
    for idx, v in enumerate(data['content'].unique()):
        dct[f'x{idx}'] = data.loc[data['content'] == v]
        idx_list.append(idx)
        xs = dct[f'x{idx}'].Time
        yB = dct[f'x{idx}'].Weight
        yA = dct[f'x{idx}'].Height


        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(10,8))

        legends = ['Weight', 'Height']

        ax.plot(xs, yB,  linestyle = ':', color ='#4c4c4c', linewidth = 4.0)
        ax.plot(xs, yA, color = '#fac346', linewidth = 3.0)

        ax.legend(legends, loc = 'lower center', ncol = len(legends), bbox_to_anchor = (0.5, -0.15), frameon = False) 
    
        ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, decimals = None, symbol ='%', is_latex = False))

        ax.set_xticks(xs[::4])
        ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelrotation = 45, labelsize = 10)

        ax.yaxis.grid()

        new_idx = [x+1 for x in idx_list]

for graph in range(total+1):
    if graph != 0:
       for ids in set(new_idx):
           print('Graph {0} ID {1}'.format(graph, ids))
           fig.savefig('Graph {0} ID {1}.jpg'.format(graph, ids))
```

I want each graph to save under the file names:

- Graph 1 ID 1
- Graph 1 ID 2
- Graph 2 ID 1
- Graph 2 ID 2
- Graph 3 ID 1
- Graph 3 ID 2

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You saved `fig` over and over. You want to save different images in your loop.

Comment: @youaresoconfused I have posted an answer, but I can not check it without proper data. The way you keep track of the graph and ID numbers is strange. I assume you *know* that there are only 3 graphs and that all graphs have the same number of IDs

Comment: @azelcer Thanks for your post, it really helped clear things up. In this particular example, I know that there are 3 graphs but that won't be the case all the time. I realized I was complicating things. Your solution does work against the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not keep a reference to each figure, so when you call `fig.savefig` in the final loop you are actually saving the figure referenced by `fig` (which is the last figure) each time. There are many ways to manage this: you can save the figure in the same loop that created it, you can assign a unique name to each figure, or you can keep a reference to each figure in a list. The first option is simpler:

```py
dct = {}  # I assume this dict is used for something after saving the figures. Otherwise it is not necessary


for i, df in enumerate(graph_list):
    data = pd.DataFrame(df)
    for idx, v in enumerate(data['content'].unique()):
        dct[f'x{idx}'] = data.loc[data['content'] == v]

        xs = dct[f'x{idx}'].Time
        yB = dct[f'x{idx}'].Weight
        yA = dct[f'x{idx}'].Height

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

        legends = ['Weight', 'Height']

        ax.plot(xs, yB,  linestyle=':', color='#4c4c4c', linewidth=4.0)
        ax.plot(xs, yA, color='#fac346', linewidth=3.0)

        ax.legend(legends, loc='lower center', ncol=len(legends),
                  bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15), frameon=False)

        ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1,
                                    decimals=None, symbol='%', is_latex=False))

        ax.set_xticks(xs[::4])
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45, labelsize=10)

        ax.yaxis.grid()

        print('Graph {0} ID {1}'.format(i+1, idx+1))
        fig.savefig('Graph {0} ID {1}.jpg'.format(i+1, idx+1))
        plt.close(fig)  # if you do not need to leave the figures open
```